# Feature request : Answer rating and default ordering

Tags: feature-request, answers

I feel following some aspects on answers could be looked at to improve the quality while rewarding the good answer.

- Ordering by default seems to be on votes, a good answer which doesnt have as many or no votes compared to an average answer having a lot of votes gets suppressed in the bottom. Can that be corrected or improved in some way?
- Many questions have only one answer for a long time, and they dont get accepted or votes, is there any way timeout mechanism to auto accept an answer? or an answer having minimum 2 votes?
- Currently it seems like the first guy answering the question seems to get most rewards instead of the best answer, could that be somehow avoided by having a locking time?

**Edit**

- One additional killer of good answer is a long post containing almost no stuff. I've read awesome posts which run long, but they are few. A long answer frustrates people looking at answers and they move on before they see other good answers sitting in the bottom. It might be a good idea to associate weight and sink the long answers not getting upvotes to bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Ordering by default seems to be on votes, a good answer which doesnt have as many or no votes compared to an average answer having a lot of votes gets suppressed in the bottom. Can that be corrected or improved in some way?

Yes - by voting. Up-vote the good answer and leave a comment explaining why. Leave a comment on the mediocre answer explaining that while it's not wrong it's not the best one.

As for your other points they have been done to death already. Search for "Fastest Gun In The West" (FGITW) for more questions and answers on your last point in particular.

Answer (score 1):

You can't lock a question / answer even for 5 minutes to avoid FGITW because all you'll get instead is a dozen similar answers (on the type of 'write-me-a-code-snippet' questions that attract FGITW) being imposed on the OP - and the OP will have no way of distinguishing between them.

FGITW can be irritating but its a reasonable method to break a tie - and it stops the same answer being made repeatedly.